# JavaScript webpage version comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In order to expedite our 'content update review process', which is used in approving web page content for publishing, I'm looking to implement a JavaScript function that will compare two webpage versions.

So far, I've created a page that will load the content to be compared from the new and old versions of a particular page.  Is there a (relatively) simple way to iterate through the html of each using JavaScript/jQuery and highlight what content has changed or is missing?

Since there would be so many html-specific details (since this is essentially html text comare), is there a JavaScript library I can use?

I should add that my first would be to implement this in PHP.  Unfortunately, we have many constraints that only permit us to use limited resources such as JavaScript.

Comment: Does it have to be Javascript? Are server side languages out of the question?

Comment: It's possible we could do it in ASP.NET, but I'll be honest.  I work in a public institution and doing anything that involves actual coding requires IT department oversight.  Unfortunately, we need to get this done in less than a year...

Comment: If you're looking to "do no actual coding", port the cite to a CMS.

Comment: JavaScript coding *is* "actual coding", and it will probably be far more difficult to generate a diff of the DOM via JS than it would be to generate a diff of the markup server-side.

Comment: @meagar I agree with your comments.  My reference to 'actual coding' was meant to discuss a server-side solution using php or asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Version Control is a **non-trivial problem**. It's probably not something you should implement from scratch, either, if this is part of your "content update review process."

Instead, consider using a tool like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [Git](https://github.com/), or your favorite source control solution.

If you *really* wanna do this, you can go from something as simple as Regex matching to DOM matching. There's no "magic library" that I'm aware of that will encapsulate this for you, so it'll be work. Work that you'll probably do wrong.

Seriously consider a version control provider, or use a CMS that has built in versioning of pages. If you're feeling squirrely, check out an open source CMS (like [Drupal](http://drupal.org)) and try to figure out how they implement versioning, then reverse engineer/re-engineer it yourself. I hope the inefficiency in that is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in 3 steps

1/ segment the content into 2 arrays

for each page
  . choose a separator, like the "." or "" 
  . you have the content as a big string, split it and build an array

2/ compare the arrays

loop on these 2 arrays containing the segmented content, let's say A[idxA] and B[idxB]
  . if A[idxA] == B[idxB] then idxA++ and idxB++
  . else find if there is an index where A[idxA] == B[index]
  . if there is, mark all indexes between idxB and index as "B modified"
  . else, mark idxA as "A modified"

3/ display the differences

At the end you should have all the indexes where A and B are not equal. You can then join the 2 arrays after adding some markups to highlight the differences.

It is not a perfect solution, it will be wrong sometimes.. But not often if you choose your separator correctly. If you want it perfect, you will have to test several match and compute the number of differences in order to minimise it